# How to redirect desktop site for wap and SEMC browser to mobile site using php

Tags: php, wap, wml

I am trying to redirect desktop site for Wap and SEMC broswers to mobile site using php.

I am using this code but it is not working.

Edit -

No errors are coming. Only it is not redirecting.

User agent strings are like this -

Micromax X267/R2AE SEMC-Browser/4.0.3 Profile/MOP-2.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.1

Please suggest.

Code -

```
<?php
$useragent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
if(strpos('SEMC-Browser/i',$useragent))
{
header('Location: http://m.yourmobilesite.com');
}

?>
```

Comment: Why isn't it working? What errors are you getting?

Comment: In what way is it not working. Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: No errors. Only it is not redirecting

===============

I will edit and post in the question

Answer (score 0):

Assuming user-agent strings of SMEC browser are like

CELKON.C64/R2AE SEMC-Browser/4.0.3 Profile/MIDP-2.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.1

Micromax X088/R2AE SEMC-Browser/4.0.3 Profile/MIDP-2.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.1

You should use the following:

```
if (strpos($useragent, 'SEMC-Browser/') !== false) {
    // redirect
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. 

Put your code.Now getting an error as follows - 

"Warning : Cannot modify header information.- headers already sent by output started at /srv/disk4/1803106/..../index.php on line ..."

Comment: You cannot send any output (e.g. output HTML) before calling header(...).